# A null char in c

Tags: c, char

I have this code in C:

```
 char c;
 char *s;

 ....

 while(1){
    c = *(s++)
    if(!c){
       exit(1);
    }
    ....
 }
```

What does (!c) do? how can I reach the exit call?

Comment: `!c` will be true when the value of `c` is 0. Some representations for 0 (besides the literal 0) are `false`, `'\0'` (aka NUL char), and `NULL`.

Comment: You can learn a lot by stepping through code with a debugger.

Comment: This has nothing to do with "x86" or any other architecture, by the way. This question is really a basic C principle, that `0` represents false, and any other value represents true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!c` always evaluates to `false` except when `c==0`, that is `c=='\0'`. Therefore the code will exit when the end of the string that `s` is pointing to is reached. (Assuming `s` points to a null-terminated string).

Note that `c = *(s++)` gets one character of the string and moves the pointer to the next character.

Comment: A string is always null-terminated by definition. If not, then it's not a string. So saying null-terminated string is redundant.

Comment: @ajay: sure, but the OP does not *call* his `*s` a string, nor does he imply it is a string. So it can hold any sort of char data (it still needs to be a zero-terminated list-- in that it is equal to a standard C string).